# Can't get Driver Updates to silently install

Tags: powershell, exe, start-process

I am having trouble getting my Driver Update .exe files to install silently using powershell.

I've been tasked with remotely installing critical driver updates on a bunch of laptops. I've stored all the driver updates on a local repository and I am using LogMeIn to run a small script on a large number of computers that will run the files.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "\\netpath\of\my\driver\updates" -Filter *.exe | 
ForEach {Start-Process $_.Fullname -ArgumentList "/S" }
```

The .exe files should install silently but they still bring up the install wizard. I have tried lots of different combinations of /s /v/qn  and no other ticket I have looked at has solved my issue.

Comment: Are you able to get the MSI variant of the install or have you checked the install manual for the specific driver manufacturer?

Comment: Its a Dell Driver and I can't find anywhere to get an MSI variant.

Comment: You should contact Dell Support and see if they have support for this option. Otherwise I believe windows has an option which will let you run the installer and spits out a configuration file which you can use to run a silent install

Comment: I would suggest on checking this solution SCConfigMgr has made for Drivers updating and installation through Modern Management [link]( https://www.scconfigmgr.com/2017/12/04/modern-management-automating-intune-enrolled-device-driver-updates/), They support Dell, Lenovo and HP, and I used it as a template to fit the requirements i needed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look in to both of those options